# Realscripts package not working in TeXLive 2017 (MacTeX)

Tags: superscripts, texlive-2017

The realscripts package does not seem to have any impact in TeXLive 2017 (MacTeX) when compiling with XeLaTeX. I updated my TeX distribution yesterday, and I notice that my footnote marks are no longer real superscripts. I have tested with Linux Libertine O. The document compiles fine otherwise. Any help will be appreciated.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
A\textsuperscript{1234567890}Z A\textsuperscript*{1234567890}Z
A\realsuperscript{1234567890}Z \\
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm: it uses real superscripts with TL 2015, but not with TL 2016 and 2017. This for XeLaTeX, as with LuaLaTeX (TL 2017) it works fine.

Comment: Yes. It seems to compile fine with LuaLaTeX but not with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for `\realsuperscript` reads

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript {m} {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
  {
    \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
    { \fontspec_if_feature:nTF {+sups}
      { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
    { \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
      { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
  }
  { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
}
```

However, with TL 2016 and later, the test

```
\fontspec_if_feature:nTF {+sups}
```

returns false with XeLaTeX and true with LuaLaTeX.

Temporary workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript {m} {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
  {
    \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
    { \fontspec_if_feature:nTF {sups}
      { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
    { \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
      { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
  }
  { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

A\textsuperscript{1234567890}Z A\textsuperscript*{1234567890}Z
A\realsuperscript{1234567890}Z \\
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Issue filed at https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/293

Comment: Thanks. This workaround works, though I now have lot of extra code in my preamble. Any idea how this can be reported to the `realscripts` package maintainer?

Comment: @user10050 I filed an issue report at the github repository