# realscripts/fontspec update vs. some Opentype fonts

Tags: xetex, fontspec, typography, superscripts, opentype

I have a file that was running smoothly a few weeks ago and is now stopping with the message:

```
 Argument of \__fontspec_strip_leading_sign:Nw has an extra }
```

Using most system fonts, or Amiri, Junicode, Libertine... there is no problem, but here is a MWE with some popular fonts that are stopping the compilation with the error above. My particular file uses an Opentype Storm Baskerville, also stopping.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}

\setromanfont{Minion Pro}
%\setromanfont{Palatino}
%\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
A\textsuperscript{1234567890}Z
\end{document}
```

I suspect my problem is very similar to [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373920/realscripts-package-not-working-in-texlive-2017-mactex), but I don't know how to adapt the answer to my particular case. Most grateful for any hack, regardless of ugliness.

I wonder if this problem is related to `fontspec`'s December update?

Comment: Have you updated your TeX system? This should be sorted ...

Comment: yes, I ran TeX Live Utility, which reduced the problem, but I'm still having trouble  with a few fonts as mentioned above. You make me wonder if I have some local dinosaur hiding in my folders... will check right now

Comment: confirmed, same problem on another machine (also a Mac) with all files updated today, and I also checked the log for old packages, but everything seems up to date

Comment: @JosephWright It fails for me with a current fontspec (with times), it works again with the development code.

Comment: Imho it is related to https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/349. (Times is one of the fonts without dflt script).

Comment: Sorry everyone, new version just sent to CTAN that should fix this.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in `v2.7` of `fontspec`, just wait until TeX Live and MiKTeX catches up. BTW, I believe `\setromanfont` is depreciated (there is no single trace of it in the current documentation), use `\setmainfont` instead, `:)`